# How to create a daemon app running with Oauth 2.0 Password grant?

Tags: oauth-2.0, passwords, sql-grant, trustpilot

I'm fairly new to working with Oauth 2.0, and the place I'm interning asked me to create an app that is runnable from the console and uses the OAuth 2.0 Password grant.
I'm really stumped as to where to start in general. I'd like to write it in either C# or java.

I'd like the app to run once every 24 hours and in extend to that, to run it from powershell using something like `run myProgram.exe`

The app needs to use webhooks to call the API.

- How do I approach this? I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
- What kind of project should I create?

I've tried reading a lot of documentation, and know how to do the most of it on paper, but I found the documentation for the initial steps lacking.

Hope you'll be able to help :) Thanks!

**Edit:**

I realize the question might have been a little too broad.

Essentially, I'd like know if I can create a serverside-web app, without any UI only console-output, that:

1. connects and gets an accesstoken from the authentication server,
2. Makes the API-calls
3. Can be converted to a .exe-file.

Hope that clears it up a bit :)

Comment: Welcome FrkKryds! Have you asked your internship for help? The question as it is appears to me very broad. Btw get your order right. First language then IDE ;)

Comment: @leun4m - My colleguages don't know how to do it either. They're currently looking for new developers, since the one they had, got a new job offer and stopped a month ago, which leaves me as the only one have just the faintest knowledge of this. 
Also, never head about that order. Thanks ;) I'm just used to only using VS19 and VSCode. I'm really at a lost of which kind of project I should start out with.

Can I create a webapp on localhost, which just runs my calls and export it to an .exe?

Comment: Well, I mean, it is okay to have an already set IDE. But if that's the case you should then stick to the language(s) it is primary designed for. Of course you can just use any texteditor to write anything but if you mean to create something productive then IDEs can offer great help for the languages they are  _designed_ for. So in case of VS I would argue **C#** would be the better choice.